map migration : google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement
I am trying to migrate in accordance with the changed regulations of Google Maps.
google.maps.Marker -->
google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement
however, It is difficult to edit the information recorded in Google Maps alone. Other than this, which part should be modified?
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advanced-markers/migration?hl=ko
//first load map
    map(data, txt = "", zoom = 9, bool = true) {
        let mapOptions = {
            zoom: zoom,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };


        let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
            mapOptions);


        if (txt == 'seoul') {
            map.setCenter({ lat: 37.245807, lng: 127.057375 });

        } else {
            let address = txt;

            let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                } else {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
            });
        }

        let marker

        let i = 0

        let infoPop = []

        data.forEach(({ name, postal, road, phone, option1, option2, location }) => {
            let lat = parseFloat(data[i].location.split(',')[0].replaceAll('(', '').replaceAll(' ', ''))
            let lng = parseFloat(data[i].location.split(',')[1].replaceAll(")", '').replaceAll(' ', ''))

            marker = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
                position: { lat, lng },
                i,
                map
            });
      


Update your map initialisation to include the mapId, by modifying your options object:
let mapOptions = {
    zoom: zoom,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapId: 'INSERT_MAP_ID'
};

Create your marker:
marker = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
            map: map,
            position: { lat, lng }
        });

And don't forget you must load the 'markers' library from the Google Maps Javascript API.
